# JavaFX 3-D pie chart with Java 8

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

Is there any example of 3-D pie chart for the latest Java 8 which uses the modern 3-D API?

I found this old example which still works https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/1485144

But I would like to use the 3-D API from Java 8.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaFX 3-D Bar chart with Java 8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22783207/javafx-3-d-bar-chart-with-java-8)