# JavaFX 3-D Bar chart with Java 8

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

Is there any example of 3-D Bar chart for the latest Java 8 which uses the modern 3-D API?

I would like to use the 3-D API from Java 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to this example, it shows use of 3-D bar chart if it helps you.
http://www.jroller.com/dgilbert/entry/creating_3d_charts_in_java

Comment: Look good but I don't see JavaFX in it. I need example with JavaFX.

Comment: You are correct, there is no JavaFX in the linked example (the Orson Charts library uses plain Java2D for the rendering).

Answer (score 4):

There was a 3d-Bar-Chart demo in the earlier versions of JavaFX, but that was removed.

You can create a bar chart yourself. Just create a grid and some boxes on it. Here's a slight modification of the answer in [How to create a 3d / surface chart with JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31073007/how-to-create-a-3d-surface-chart-with-javafx/31125736#31125736). Drag around via mouse, use mouse wheel to zoom.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.PerspectiveCamera;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.SceneAntialiasing;
import javafx.scene.input.ScrollEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.paint.Paint;
import javafx.scene.paint.PhongMaterial;
import javafx.scene.shape.Box;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.transform.Rotate;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class BarChart3dDemo extends Application {

    private static Random rnd = new Random();

    // size of graph
    int graphSize = 400;

    // variables for mouse interaction
    private double mousePosX, mousePosY;
    private double mouseOldX, mouseOldY;
    private final Rotate rotateX = new Rotate(20, Rotate.X_AXIS);
    private final Rotate rotateY = new Rotate(-45, Rotate.Y_AXIS);

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        // create axis walls
        Group grid = createGrid(graphSize);

        // initial cube rotation
        grid.getTransforms().addAll(rotateX, rotateY);

        // add objects to scene
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(grid);

        // create bars
        double gridSizeHalf = graphSize / 2;
        double size = 30;
        for (double i = -gridSizeHalf + size; i < gridSizeHalf; i += 50) {
            for (double j = -gridSizeHalf + size; j < gridSizeHalf; j += 50) {

                double height = rnd.nextDouble() * 300;

                Box box = new Box(size, height, size);

                // color
                PhongMaterial mat = new PhongMaterial();
                mat.setDiffuseColor(randomColor());
                box.setMaterial(mat);

                // location
                box.setLayoutY(-height * 0.5 + graphSize * 0.5);
                box.setTranslateX(i);
                box.setTranslateZ(j);

                grid.getChildren().addAll(box);

            }
        }

        // scene
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1600, 900, true, SceneAntialiasing.BALANCED);
        scene.setCamera(new PerspectiveCamera());

        scene.setOnMousePressed(me -> {
            mouseOldX = me.getSceneX();
            mouseOldY = me.getSceneY();
        });
        scene.setOnMouseDragged(me -> {
            mousePosX = me.getSceneX();
            mousePosY = me.getSceneY();
            rotateX.setAngle(rotateX.getAngle() - (mousePosY - mouseOldY));
            rotateY.setAngle(rotateY.getAngle() + (mousePosX - mouseOldX));
            mouseOldX = mousePosX;
            mouseOldY = mousePosY;

        });

        makeZoomable(root);

        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    /**
     * Axis wall
     */
    public static class Axis extends Pane {

        Rectangle wall;

        public Axis(double size) {

            // wall
            // first the wall, then the lines => overlapping of lines over walls
            // works
            wall = new Rectangle(size, size);
            getChildren().add(wall);

            // grid
            double zTranslate = 0;
            double lineWidth = 1.0;
            Color gridColor = Color.WHITE;

            for (int y = 0; y <= size; y += size / 10) {

                Line line = new Line(0, 0, size, 0);
                line.setStroke(gridColor);
                line.setFill(gridColor);
                line.setTranslateY(y);
                line.setTranslateZ(zTranslate);
                line.setStrokeWidth(lineWidth);

                getChildren().addAll(line);

            }

            for (int x = 0; x <= size; x += size / 10) {

                Line line = new Line(0, 0, 0, size);
                line.setStroke(gridColor);
                line.setFill(gridColor);
                line.setTranslateX(x);
                line.setTranslateZ(zTranslate);
                line.setStrokeWidth(lineWidth);

                getChildren().addAll(line);

            }

        }

        public void setFill(Paint paint) {
            wall.setFill(paint);
        }

    }

    public void makeZoomable(StackPane control) {

        final double MAX_SCALE = 20.0;
        final double MIN_SCALE = 0.1;

        control.addEventFilter(ScrollEvent.ANY, new EventHandler<ScrollEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ScrollEvent event) {

                double delta = 1.2;

                double scale = control.getScaleX();

                if (event.getDeltaY() < 0) {
                    scale /= delta;
                } else {
                    scale *= delta;
                }

                scale = clamp(scale, MIN_SCALE, MAX_SCALE);

                control.setScaleX(scale);
                control.setScaleY(scale);

                event.consume();

            }

        });

    }

    /**
     * Create axis walls
     *
     * @param size
     * @return
     */
    private Group createGrid(int size) {

        Group cube = new Group();

        // size of the cube
        Color color = Color.LIGHTGRAY;

        List<Axis> cubeFaces = new ArrayList<>();
        Axis r;

        // back face
        r = new Axis(size);
        r.setFill(color.deriveColor(0.0, 1.0, (1 - 0.5 * 1), 1.0));
        r.setTranslateX(-0.5 * size);
        r.setTranslateY(-0.5 * size);
        r.setTranslateZ(0.5 * size);

        cubeFaces.add(r);

        // bottom face
        r = new Axis(size);
        r.setFill(color.deriveColor(0.0, 1.0, (1 - 0.4 * 1), 1.0));
        r.setTranslateX(-0.5 * size);
        r.setTranslateY(0);
        r.setRotationAxis(Rotate.X_AXIS);
        r.setRotate(90);

        cubeFaces.add(r);

        // right face
        r = new Axis(size);
        r.setFill(color.deriveColor(0.0, 1.0, (1 - 0.3 * 1), 1.0));
        r.setTranslateX(-1 * size);
        r.setTranslateY(-0.5 * size);
        r.setRotationAxis(Rotate.Y_AXIS);
        r.setRotate(90);

        // cubeFaces.add( r);

        // left face
        r = new Axis(size);
        r.setFill(color.deriveColor(0.0, 1.0, (1 - 0.2 * 1), 1.0));
        r.setTranslateX(0);
        r.setTranslateY(-0.5 * size);
        r.setRotationAxis(Rotate.Y_AXIS);
        r.setRotate(90);

        cubeFaces.add(r);

        // top face
        r = new Axis(size);
        r.setFill(color.deriveColor(0.0, 1.0, (1 - 0.1 * 1), 1.0));
        r.setTranslateX(-0.5 * size);
        r.setTranslateY(-1 * size);
        r.setRotationAxis(Rotate.X_AXIS);
        r.setRotate(90);

        // cubeFaces.add( r);

        // front face
        r = new Axis(size);
        r.setFill(color.deriveColor(0.0, 1.0, (1 - 0.1 * 1), 1.0));
        r.setTranslateX(-0.5 * size);
        r.setTranslateY(-0.5 * size);
        r.setTranslateZ(-0.5 * size);

        // cubeFaces.add( r);

        cube.getChildren().addAll(cubeFaces);

        return cube;
    }

    public static double normalizeValue(double value, double min, double max, double newMin, double newMax) {

        return (value - min) * (newMax - newMin) / (max - min) + newMin;

    }

    public static double clamp(double value, double min, double max) {

        if (Double.compare(value, min) < 0)
            return min;

        if (Double.compare(value, max) > 0)
            return max;

        return value;
    }

    public static Color randomColor() {
        return Color.rgb(rnd.nextInt(255), rnd.nextInt(255), rnd.nextInt(255));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: That is a bar chart example. All you have to do is add tick marks to it.

Comment: It's too advanced task for me.

Answer (score 0):

Jzy3d has nice bar charts in its [gallery](http://jzy3d.org/gallery.php). You can use Jzy3d with [JavaFX](https://github.com/jzy3d/jzy3d-api/blob/master/jzy3d-javafx/src/main/java/org/jzy3d/demos/javafx/DemoJzy3dFX.java) easily.

Comment: Is there any way to do this with core JavaFX?

Comment: I am investigating core JavaFX charts, with the help of FXyz : https://github.com/jzy3d/FXyz-1/tree/master/src/main/java/org/jzy3d/javafx