# How to create a 3d / surface chart with JavaFX?

Tags: charts, javafx

**Problem**

I tried to create a 3d chart with JavaFX but it seems to be more difficult than what one would expect.

My current way of doing it would be to create a TriangleMesh, but that's rather circumstantial. All I'd like to do is to provide a `List<Point3D>` to the chart and then the chart should be rendered as a surface.

However, even a simple pyramid with 5 data points turns out to be rather complicated:

```
    float h = 200;                    // Height
    float s = 200;                    // Side

    TriangleMesh pyramidMesh = new TriangleMesh();

    pyramidMesh.getTexCoords().addAll(0,0);
    pyramidMesh.getPoints().addAll(
            0,    0,    0,            // Point 0 - Top
            0,    h,    -s/2,         // Point 1 - Front
            -s/2, h,    0,            // Point 2 - Left
            s/2,  h,    0,            // Point 3 - Back
            0,    h,    s/2           // Point 4 - Right
        );

    pyramidMesh.getFaces().addAll(
      0,0,  2,0,  1,0,          // Front left face
      0,0,  1,0,  3,0,          // Front right face
      0,0,  3,0,  4,0,          // Back right face
      0,0,  4,0,  2,0,          // Back left face
      4,0,  1,0,  2,0,          // Bottom rear face
      4,0,  3,0,  1,0           // Bottom front face
  );
```

**Questions**

- Does anyone know how to create a 3d chart with JavaFX?
- Is a TriangleMesh the proper way to do it?
- How do you convert a `List<Point3D>` into a TriangleMesh?

**Code**

```
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.PerspectiveCamera;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.paint.PhongMaterial;
import javafx.scene.shape.Box;
import javafx.scene.shape.DrawMode;
import javafx.scene.shape.MeshView;
import javafx.scene.shape.TriangleMesh;
import javafx.scene.transform.Rotate;
import javafx.scene.transform.Scale;
import javafx.scene.transform.Translate;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class Chart3dSampleApp extends Application {

    final Group root = new Group();
    final Group axisGroup = new Group();
    final Xform world = new Xform();
    final PerspectiveCamera camera = new PerspectiveCamera(true);
    final Xform cameraXform = new Xform();
    final Xform cameraXform2 = new Xform();
    final Xform cameraXform3 = new Xform();
    final double cameraDistance = 1450;
    final Xform moleculeGroup = new Xform();
    private Timeline timeline;
    boolean timelinePlaying = false;
    double ONE_FRAME = 1.0 / 24.0;
    double DELTA_MULTIPLIER = 200.0;
    double CONTROL_MULTIPLIER = 10.1;
    double SHIFT_MULTIPLIER = 0.1;
    double ALT_MULTIPLIER = 0.5;
    double mousePosX;
    double mousePosY;
    double mouseOldX;
    double mouseOldY;
    double mouseDeltaX;
    double mouseDeltaY;

    private void buildScene() {
        root.getChildren().add(world);
    }

    private void buildCamera() {
        root.getChildren().add(cameraXform);
        cameraXform.getChildren().add(cameraXform2);
        cameraXform2.getChildren().add(cameraXform3);
        cameraXform3.getChildren().add(camera);
        cameraXform3.setRotateZ(0);

        camera.setNearClip(0.1);
        camera.setFarClip(10000.0);
        camera.setTranslateZ(-cameraDistance);
        cameraXform.ry.setAngle(0);
        cameraXform.rx.setAngle(0);
    }

    private void buildAxes() {
        final PhongMaterial redMaterial = new PhongMaterial();
        redMaterial.setDiffuseColor(Color.DARKRED);
        redMaterial.setSpecularColor(Color.RED);

        final PhongMaterial greenMaterial = new PhongMaterial();
        greenMaterial.setDiffuseColor(Color.DARKGREEN);
        greenMaterial.setSpecularColor(Color.GREEN);

        final PhongMaterial blueMaterial = new PhongMaterial();
        blueMaterial.setDiffuseColor(Color.DARKBLUE);
        blueMaterial.setSpecularColor(Color.BLUE);

        final Box xAxis = new Box(300, 1, 300);
        final Box yAxis = new Box(1, 300, 300);
        final Box zAxis = new Box(300, 300, 1);

        yAxis.setTranslateY(-150);
        yAxis.setTranslateX(150);
        zAxis.setTranslateY(-150);
        zAxis.setTranslateZ(150);

        xAxis.setMaterial(redMaterial);
        yAxis.setMaterial(greenMaterial);
        zAxis.setMaterial(blueMaterial);

        axisGroup.getChildren().addAll(xAxis, yAxis, zAxis);
        world.getChildren().addAll(axisGroup);
    }

    private void buildChart() {

      final PhongMaterial whiteMaterial = new PhongMaterial();
      whiteMaterial.setDiffuseColor(Color.WHITE);
      whiteMaterial.setSpecularColor(Color.LIGHTBLUE);

        float h = 200;                    // Height
        float s = 200;                    // Side

        TriangleMesh pyramidMesh = new TriangleMesh();

        pyramidMesh.getTexCoords().addAll(0,0);
        pyramidMesh.getPoints().addAll(
                0,    0,    0,            // Point 0 - Top
                0,    h,    -s/2,         // Point 1 - Front
                -s/2, h,    0,            // Point 2 - Left
                s/2,  h,    0,            // Point 3 - Back
                0,    h,    s/2           // Point 4 - Right
            );

        pyramidMesh.getFaces().addAll(
          0,0,  2,0,  1,0,          // Front left face
          0,0,  1,0,  3,0,          // Front right face
          0,0,  3,0,  4,0,          // Back right face
          0,0,  4,0,  2,0,          // Back left face
          4,0,  1,0,  2,0,          // Bottom rear face
          4,0,  3,0,  1,0           // Bottom front face
      ); 


        MeshView pyramid = new MeshView(pyramidMesh);
        pyramid.setDrawMode(DrawMode.FILL);
        pyramid.setMaterial(whiteMaterial);
        pyramid.setTranslateY(-h);

        world.getChildren().addAll(pyramid);
    }


    private void handleMouse(Scene scene, final Node root) {
        scene.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override public void handle(MouseEvent me) {
                mousePosX = me.getSceneX();
                mousePosY = me.getSceneY();
                mouseOldX = me.getSceneX();
                mouseOldY = me.getSceneY();
            }
        });
        scene.setOnMouseDragged(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent me) {
                mouseOldX = mousePosX;
                mouseOldY = mousePosY;
                mousePosX = me.getSceneX();
                mousePosY = me.getSceneY();
                mouseDeltaX = (mousePosX - mouseOldX);
                mouseDeltaY = (mousePosY - mouseOldY);

                double modifier = 1.0;
                double modifierFactor = 0.1;

                if (me.isControlDown()) {
                    modifier = 0.1;
                }
                if (me.isShiftDown()) {
                    modifier = 10.0;
                }
                if (me.isPrimaryButtonDown()) {
                    cameraXform.ry.setAngle(cameraXform.ry.getAngle() - mouseDeltaX * modifierFactor * modifier * 2.0);  // +
                    cameraXform.rx.setAngle(cameraXform.rx.getAngle() + mouseDeltaY * modifierFactor * modifier * 2.0);  // -
                } else if (me.isSecondaryButtonDown()) {
                    double z = camera.getTranslateZ();
                    double newZ = z + mouseDeltaX * modifierFactor * modifier;
                    camera.setTranslateZ(newZ);
                } else if (me.isMiddleButtonDown()) {
                    cameraXform2.t.setX(cameraXform2.t.getX() + mouseDeltaX * modifierFactor * modifier * 0.3);  // -
                    cameraXform2.t.setY(cameraXform2.t.getY() + mouseDeltaY * modifierFactor * modifier * 0.3);  // -
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void handleKeyboard(Scene scene, final Node root) {
        final boolean moveCamera = true;
        scene.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
                Duration currentTime;
                switch (event.getCode()) {
                    case Z:
                        if (event.isShiftDown()) {
                            cameraXform.ry.setAngle(0.0);
                            cameraXform.rx.setAngle(0.0);
                            camera.setTranslateZ(-300.0);
                        }
                        cameraXform2.t.setX(0.0);
                        cameraXform2.t.setY(0.0);
                        break;
                    case X:
                        if (event.isControlDown()) {
                            if (axisGroup.isVisible()) {
                                axisGroup.setVisible(false);
                            } else {
                                axisGroup.setVisible(true);
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    case S:
                        if (event.isControlDown()) {
                            if (moleculeGroup.isVisible()) {
                                moleculeGroup.setVisible(false);
                            } else {
                                moleculeGroup.setVisible(true);
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    case SPACE:
                        if (timelinePlaying) {
                            timeline.pause();
                            timelinePlaying = false;
                        } else {
                            timeline.play();
                            timelinePlaying = true;
                        }
                        break;
                    case UP:
                        if (event.isControlDown() && event.isShiftDown()) {
                            cameraXform2.t.setY(cameraXform2.t.getY() - 10.0 * CONTROL_MULTIPLIER);
                        } else if (event.isAltDown() && event.isShiftDown()) {
                            cameraXform.rx.setAngle(cameraXform.rx.getAngle() - 10.0 * ALT_MULTIPLIER);
                        } else if (event.isControlDown()) {
                            cameraXform2.t.setY(cameraXform2.t.getY() - 1.0 * CONTROL_MULTIPLIER);
                        } else if (event.isAltDown()) {
                            cameraXform.rx.setAngle(cameraXform.rx.getAngle() - 2.0 * ALT_MULTIPLIER);
                        } else if (event.isShiftDown()) {
                            double z = camera.getTranslateZ();
                            double newZ = z + 5.0 * SHIFT_MULTIPLIER;
                            camera.setTranslateZ(newZ);
                        }
                        break;
                    case DOWN:
                        if (event.isControlDown() && event.isShiftDown()) {
                            cameraXform2.t.setY(cameraXform2.t.getY() + 10.0 * CONTROL_MULTIPLIER);
                        } else if (event.isAltDown() && event.isShiftDown()) {
                            cameraXform.rx.setAngle(cameraXform.rx.getAngle() + 10.0 * ALT_MULTIPLIER);
                        } else if (event.isControlDown()) {
                            cameraXform2.t.setY(cameraXform2.t.getY() + 1.0 * CONTROL_MULTIPLIER);
                        } else if (event.isAltDown()) {
                            cameraXform.rx.setAngle(cameraXform.rx.getAngle() + 2.0 * ALT_MULTIPLIER);
                        } else if (event.isShiftDown()) {
                            double z = camera.getTranslateZ();
                            double newZ = z - 5.0 * SHIFT_MULTIPLIER;
                            camera.setTranslateZ(newZ);
                        }
                        break;
                    case RIGHT:
                        if (event.isControlDown() && event.isShiftDown()) {
                            cameraXform2.t.setX(cameraXform2.t.getX() + 10.0 * CONTROL_MULTIPLIER);
                        } else if (event.isAltDown() && event.isShiftDown()) {
                            cameraXform.ry.setAngle(cameraXform.ry.getAngle() - 10.0 * ALT_MULTIPLIER);
                        } else if (event.isControlDown()) {
                            cameraXform2.t.setX(cameraXform2.t.getX() + 1.0 * CONTROL_MULTIPLIER);
                        } else if (event.isAltDown()) {
                            cameraXform.ry.setAngle(cameraXform.ry.getAngle() - 2.0 * ALT_MULTIPLIER);
                        }
                        break;
                    case LEFT:
                        if (event.isControlDown() && event.isShiftDown()) {
                            cameraXform2.t.setX(cameraXform2.t.getX() - 10.0 * CONTROL_MULTIPLIER);
                        } else if (event.isAltDown() && event.isShiftDown()) {
                            cameraXform.ry.setAngle(cameraXform.ry.getAngle() + 10.0 * ALT_MULTIPLIER);  // -
                        } else if (event.isControlDown()) {
                            cameraXform2.t.setX(cameraXform2.t.getX() - 1.0 * CONTROL_MULTIPLIER);
                        } else if (event.isAltDown()) {
                            cameraXform.ry.setAngle(cameraXform.ry.getAngle() + 2.0 * ALT_MULTIPLIER);  // -
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
    }

        @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        buildScene();
        buildCamera();
        buildAxes();
        buildChart();

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1600, 900, true);
        scene.setFill(Color.GREY);
        handleKeyboard(scene, world);
        handleMouse(scene, world);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        scene.setCamera(camera);

    }

    /**
     * The main() method is ignored in correctly deployed JavaFX application.
     * main() serves only as fallback in case the application can not be
     * launched through deployment artifacts, e.g., in IDEs with limited FX
     * support. NetBeans ignores main().
     *
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("prism.dirtyopts", "false");
        launch(args);
    }

    public static class Xform extends Group {

      public enum RotateOrder {
          XYZ, XZY, YXZ, YZX, ZXY, ZYX
      }

      public Translate t  = new Translate(); 
      public Translate p  = new Translate(); 
      public Translate ip = new Translate(); 
      public Rotate rx = new Rotate();
      { rx.setAxis(Rotate.X_AXIS); }
      public Rotate ry = new Rotate();
      { ry.setAxis(Rotate.Y_AXIS); }
      public Rotate rz = new Rotate();
      { rz.setAxis(Rotate.Z_AXIS); }
      public Scale s = new Scale();

      public Xform() { 
          super(); 
          getTransforms().addAll(t, rz, ry, rx, s); 
      }

      public Xform(RotateOrder rotateOrder) { 
          super(); 
          // choose the order of rotations based on the rotateOrder
          switch (rotateOrder) {
          case XYZ:
              getTransforms().addAll(t, p, rz, ry, rx, s, ip); 
              break;
          case XZY:
              getTransforms().addAll(t, p, ry, rz, rx, s, ip); 
              break;
          case YXZ:
              getTransforms().addAll(t, p, rz, rx, ry, s, ip); 
              break;
          case YZX:
              getTransforms().addAll(t, p, rx, rz, ry, s, ip);  // For Camera
              break;
          case ZXY:
              getTransforms().addAll(t, p, ry, rx, rz, s, ip); 
              break;
          case ZYX:
              getTransforms().addAll(t, p, rx, ry, rz, s, ip); 
              break;
          }
      }

      public void setTranslate(double x, double y, double z) {
          t.setX(x);
          t.setY(y);
          t.setZ(z);
      }

      public void setTranslate(double x, double y) {
          t.setX(x);
          t.setY(y);
      }

      // Cannot override these methods as they are final:
      // public void setTranslateX(double x) { t.setX(x); }
      // public void setTranslateY(double y) { t.setY(y); }
      // public void setTranslateZ(double z) { t.setZ(z); }
      // Use these methods instead:
      public void setTx(double x) { t.setX(x); }
      public void setTy(double y) { t.setY(y); }
      public void setTz(double z) { t.setZ(z); }

      public void setRotate(double x, double y, double z) {
          rx.setAngle(x);
          ry.setAngle(y);
          rz.setAngle(z);
      }

      public void setRotateX(double x) { rx.setAngle(x); }
      public void setRotateY(double y) { ry.setAngle(y); }
      public void setRotateZ(double z) { rz.setAngle(z); }
      public void setRx(double x) { rx.setAngle(x); }
      public void setRy(double y) { ry.setAngle(y); }
      public void setRz(double z) { rz.setAngle(z); }

      public void setScale(double scaleFactor) {
          s.setX(scaleFactor);
          s.setY(scaleFactor);
          s.setZ(scaleFactor);
      }

      public void setScale(double x, double y, double z) {
          s.setX(x);
          s.setY(y);
          s.setZ(z);
      }

      // Cannot override these methods as they are final:
      // public void setScaleX(double x) { s.setX(x); }
      // public void setScaleY(double y) { s.setY(y); }
      // public void setScaleZ(double z) { s.setZ(z); }
      // Use these methods instead:
      public void setSx(double x) { s.setX(x); }
      public void setSy(double y) { s.setY(y); }
      public void setSz(double z) { s.setZ(z); }

      public void setPivot(double x, double y, double z) {
          p.setX(x);
          p.setY(y);
          p.setZ(z);
          ip.setX(-x);
          ip.setY(-y);
          ip.setZ(-z);
      }

      public void reset() {
          t.setX(0.0);
          t.setY(0.0);
          t.setZ(0.0);
          rx.setAngle(0.0);
          ry.setAngle(0.0);
          rz.setAngle(0.0);
          s.setX(1.0);
          s.setY(1.0);
          s.setZ(1.0);
          p.setX(0.0);
          p.setY(0.0);
          p.setZ(0.0);
          ip.setX(0.0);
          ip.setY(0.0);
          ip.setZ(0.0);
      }

      public void resetTSP() {
          t.setX(0.0);
          t.setY(0.0);
          t.setZ(0.0);
          s.setX(1.0);
          s.setY(1.0);
          s.setZ(1.0);
          p.setX(0.0);
          p.setY(0.0);
          p.setZ(0.0);
          ip.setX(0.0);
          ip.setY(0.0);
          ip.setZ(0.0);
      }
  }

}
```

The chart should be e. g. something like this:

[image]

or this:

[image]

In the end it should be possible to display e. g. [the result of perlin noise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31017749/range-of-perlin-noise-result-values), but instead of the perlin noise value being a color value, it's a height value.

Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: Yes, sure you could do it.  Jose Pereda would be better at it than me.  It would take me a long time to do it.  Perhaps the facilities in the [FXyz library](https://github.com/FXyz/FXyz) might make it easier to accomplish, however you could do it with a straight mesh to which you apply a [displacement map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Displacement_mapping).  You could instead use a [bump map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_mapping) by calculating normals and applying that (PhongMaterial supports this), but directly modifying the mesh geometry through displacement is probably best.

Comment: Actually, [FXyz](https://github.com/FXyz/FXyz) already has a `SurfacePlotMesh` implementation, where you can just add a `Function<Point3D,Number>` to be plotted, even adding some density map for the texture, like in [here](https://twitter.com/jdub1581/status/569603677419278336) or [here](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/B-ehScMIcAA8dXc.png). You can try the sampler from [here](https://github.com/FXyz/FXyz/releases). We also have a `CubeViewer` as a frame for the plot, so the only missing part are the labels. If I have the time I can work on it...

Comment: [This was something interesting](https://github.com/miho/JavaOne2013) I remember, it even does 3d chart videos.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Thanks to [NwDx's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31110292/why-is-the-diffuse-map-not-applied-to-my-meshview) I managed to create something useful. It's not a complete chart application and I hope someone with more know how can provide a better answer, but I'll post the result nontheless.

You can use mouse dragging for rotation and mouse wheel for zooming. The example shows a perlin noise graph with a diffuse map that is used on the mesh.

The core isn't actually much code. It's just about turning a 2d-array into a mesh:

```
    // perlin noise
    float[][] noiseArray = createNoise( size);

    // mesh
    TriangleMesh mesh = new TriangleMesh();

    // create points for x/z
    float amplification = 100; // amplification of noise

    for (int x = 0; x < size; x++) {
        for (int z = 0; z < size; z++) {
            mesh.getPoints().addAll(x, noiseArray[x][z] * amplification, z);
        }
    }

    // texture
    int length = size;
    float total = length;

    for (float x = 0; x < length - 1; x++) {
        for (float y = 0; y < length - 1; y++) {

            float x0 = x / total;
            float y0 = y / total;
            float x1 = (x + 1) / total;
            float y1 = (y + 1) / total;

            mesh.getTexCoords().addAll( //
                    x0, y0, // 0, top-left
                    x0, y1, // 1, bottom-left
                    x1, y1, // 2, top-right
                    x1, y1 // 3, bottom-right
            );


        }
    }

    // faces
    for (int x = 0; x < length - 1; x++) {
        for (int z = 0; z < length - 1; z++) {

            int tl = x * length + z; // top-left
            int bl = x * length + z + 1; // bottom-left
            int tr = (x + 1) * length + z; // top-right
            int br = (x + 1) * length + z + 1; // bottom-right

            int offset = (x * (length - 1) + z ) * 8 / 2; // div 2 because we have u AND v in the list

            // working
            mesh.getFaces().addAll(bl, offset + 1, tl, offset + 0, tr, offset + 2);
            mesh.getFaces().addAll(tr, offset + 2, br, offset + 3, bl, offset + 1);

        }
    }
```

If someone has a better algorithm, please do share it. I don't mind if you reuse the code.

The full working example:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Point3D;
import javafx.scene.DepthTest;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.PerspectiveCamera;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.SceneAntialiasing;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.image.PixelWriter;
import javafx.scene.image.WritableImage;
import javafx.scene.input.ScrollEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.paint.CycleMethod;
import javafx.scene.paint.LinearGradient;
import javafx.scene.paint.Paint;
import javafx.scene.paint.PhongMaterial;
import javafx.scene.paint.Stop;
import javafx.scene.shape.CullFace;
import javafx.scene.shape.DrawMode;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.scene.shape.MeshView;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.shape.TriangleMesh;
import javafx.scene.transform.Rotate;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Chart3dDemo extends Application {

    // size of graph
    int size = 400;

    // variables for mouse interaction
    private double mousePosX, mousePosY;
    private double mouseOldX, mouseOldY;
    private final Rotate rotateX = new Rotate(20, Rotate.X_AXIS);
    private final Rotate rotateY = new Rotate(-45, Rotate.Y_AXIS);

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        // create axis walls
        Group cube = createCube(size);

        // initial cube rotation
        cube.getTransforms().addAll(rotateX, rotateY);

        // add objects to scene
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(cube);

        // perlin noise
        float[][] noiseArray = createNoise( size);

        // mesh
        TriangleMesh mesh = new TriangleMesh();

        // create points for x/z
        float amplification = 100; // amplification of noise

        for (int x = 0; x < size; x++) {
            for (int z = 0; z < size; z++) {
                mesh.getPoints().addAll(x, noiseArray[x][z] * amplification, z);
            }
        }

        // texture
        int length = size;
        float total = length;

        for (float x = 0; x < length - 1; x++) {
            for (float y = 0; y < length - 1; y++) {

                float x0 = x / total;
                float y0 = y / total;
                float x1 = (x + 1) / total;
                float y1 = (y + 1) / total;

                mesh.getTexCoords().addAll( //
                        x0, y0, // 0, top-left
                        x0, y1, // 1, bottom-left
                        x1, y1, // 2, top-right
                        x1, y1 // 3, bottom-right
                );


            }
        }

        // faces
        for (int x = 0; x < length - 1; x++) {
            for (int z = 0; z < length - 1; z++) {

                int tl = x * length + z; // top-left
                int bl = x * length + z + 1; // bottom-left
                int tr = (x + 1) * length + z; // top-right
                int br = (x + 1) * length + z + 1; // bottom-right

                int offset = (x * (length - 1) + z ) * 8 / 2; // div 2 because we have u AND v in the list

                // working
                mesh.getFaces().addAll(bl, offset + 1, tl, offset + 0, tr, offset + 2);
                mesh.getFaces().addAll(tr, offset + 2, br, offset + 3, bl, offset + 1);

            }
        }


        // material
        Image diffuseMap = createImage(size, noiseArray);

        PhongMaterial material = new PhongMaterial();
        material.setDiffuseMap(diffuseMap);
        material.setSpecularColor(Color.WHITE);

        // mesh view
        MeshView meshView = new MeshView(mesh);
        meshView.setTranslateX(-0.5 * size);
        meshView.setTranslateZ(-0.5 * size);
        meshView.setMaterial(material);
        meshView.setCullFace(CullFace.NONE);
        meshView.setDrawMode(DrawMode.FILL);
        meshView.setDepthTest(DepthTest.ENABLE);

        cube.getChildren().addAll(meshView);

        // testing / debugging stuff: show diffuse map on chart
        ImageView iv = new ImageView(diffuseMap);
        iv.setTranslateX(-0.5 * size);
        iv.setTranslateY(-0.10 * size);
        iv.setRotate(90);
        iv.setRotationAxis(new Point3D(1, 0, 0));
        cube.getChildren().add(iv);

        // scene
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1600, 900, true, SceneAntialiasing.BALANCED);
        scene.setCamera(new PerspectiveCamera());

        scene.setOnMousePressed(me -> {
            mouseOldX = me.getSceneX();
            mouseOldY = me.getSceneY();
        });
        scene.setOnMouseDragged(me -> {
            mousePosX = me.getSceneX();
            mousePosY = me.getSceneY();
            rotateX.setAngle(rotateX.getAngle() - (mousePosY - mouseOldY));
            rotateY.setAngle(rotateY.getAngle() + (mousePosX - mouseOldX));
            mouseOldX = mousePosX;
            mouseOldY = mousePosY;

        });

        makeZoomable(root);

        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();


    }

    /**
     * Create texture for uv mapping
     * @param size
     * @param noise
     * @return
     */
    public Image createImage(double size, float[][] noise) {

        int width = (int) size;
        int height = (int) size;

        WritableImage wr = new WritableImage(width, height);
        PixelWriter pw = wr.getPixelWriter();
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {

                float value = noise[x][y];

                double gray = normalizeValue(value, -.5, .5, 0., 1.);

                gray = clamp(gray, 0, 1);

                Color color = Color.RED.interpolate(Color.YELLOW, gray);

                pw.setColor(x, y, color);

            }
        }

        return wr;

    }

    /**
     * Axis wall
     */
    public static class Axis extends Pane {

        Rectangle wall;

        public Axis(double size) {

            // wall
            // first the wall, then the lines => overlapping of lines over walls
            // works
            wall = new Rectangle(size, size);
            getChildren().add(wall);

            // grid
            double zTranslate = 0;
            double lineWidth = 1.0;
            Color gridColor = Color.WHITE;

            for (int y = 0; y <= size; y += size / 10) {

                Line line = new Line(0, 0, size, 0);
                line.setStroke(gridColor);
                line.setFill(gridColor);
                line.setTranslateY(y);
                line.setTranslateZ(zTranslate);
                line.setStrokeWidth(lineWidth);

                getChildren().addAll(line);

            }

            for (int x = 0; x <= size; x += size / 10) {

                Line line = new Line(0, 0, 0, size);
                line.setStroke(gridColor);
                line.setFill(gridColor);
                line.setTranslateX(x);
                line.setTranslateZ(zTranslate);
                line.setStrokeWidth(lineWidth);

                getChildren().addAll(line);

            }

            // labels
            // TODO: for some reason the text makes the wall have an offset
            // for( int y=0; y <= size; y+=size/10) {
            //
            // Text text = new Text( ""+y);
            // text.setTranslateX(size + 10);
            //
            // text.setTranslateY(y);
            // text.setTranslateZ(zTranslate);
            //
            // getChildren().addAll(text);
            //
            // }

        }

        public void setFill(Paint paint) {
            wall.setFill(paint);
        }

    }

    public void makeZoomable(StackPane control) {

        final double MAX_SCALE = 20.0;
        final double MIN_SCALE = 0.1;

        control.addEventFilter(ScrollEvent.ANY, new EventHandler<ScrollEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ScrollEvent event) {

                double delta = 1.2;

                double scale = control.getScaleX();

                if (event.getDeltaY() < 0) {
                    scale /= delta;
                } else {
                    scale *= delta;
                }

                scale = clamp(scale, MIN_SCALE, MAX_SCALE);

                control.setScaleX(scale);
                control.setScaleY(scale);

                event.consume();

            }

        });

    }

    /**
     * Create axis walls
     * @param size
     * @return
     */
    private Group createCube(int size) {

        Group cube = new Group();

        // size of the cube
        Color color = Color.DARKCYAN;

        List<Axis> cubeFaces = new ArrayList<>();
        Axis r;

        // back face
        r = new Axis(size);
        r.setFill(color.deriveColor(0.0, 1.0, (1 - 0.5 * 1), 1.0));
        r.setTranslateX(-0.5 * size);
        r.setTranslateY(-0.5 * size);
        r.setTranslateZ(0.5 * size);

        cubeFaces.add(r);

        // bottom face
        r = new Axis(size);
        r.setFill(color.deriveColor(0.0, 1.0, (1 - 0.4 * 1), 1.0));
        r.setTranslateX(-0.5 * size);
        r.setTranslateY(0);
        r.setRotationAxis(Rotate.X_AXIS);
        r.setRotate(90);

        cubeFaces.add(r);

        // right face
        r = new Axis(size);
        r.setFill(color.deriveColor(0.0, 1.0, (1 - 0.3 * 1), 1.0));
        r.setTranslateX(-1 * size);
        r.setTranslateY(-0.5 * size);
        r.setRotationAxis(Rotate.Y_AXIS);
        r.setRotate(90);

        // cubeFaces.add( r);

        // left face
        r = new Axis(size);
        r.setFill(color.deriveColor(0.0, 1.0, (1 - 0.2 * 1), 1.0));
        r.setTranslateX(0);
        r.setTranslateY(-0.5 * size);
        r.setRotationAxis(Rotate.Y_AXIS);
        r.setRotate(90);

        cubeFaces.add(r);

        // top face
        r = new Axis(size);
        r.setFill(color.deriveColor(0.0, 1.0, (1 - 0.1 * 1), 1.0));
        r.setTranslateX(-0.5 * size);
        r.setTranslateY(-1 * size);
        r.setRotationAxis(Rotate.X_AXIS);
        r.setRotate(90);

        // cubeFaces.add( r);

        // front face
        r = new Axis(size);
        r.setFill(color.deriveColor(0.0, 1.0, (1 - 0.1 * 1), 1.0));
        r.setTranslateX(-0.5 * size);
        r.setTranslateY(-0.5 * size);
        r.setTranslateZ(-0.5 * size);

        // cubeFaces.add( r);

        cube.getChildren().addAll(cubeFaces);

        return cube;
    }

    /**
     * Create an array of the given size with values of perlin noise
     * @param size
     * @return
     */
    private float[][] createNoise( int size) {
        float[][] noiseArray = new float[(int) size][(int) size];

        for (int x = 0; x < size; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < size; y++) {

                double frequency = 10.0 / (double) size;

                double noise = ImprovedNoise.noise(x * frequency, y * frequency, 0);

                noiseArray[x][y] = (float) noise;
            }
        }

        return noiseArray;

    }

    public static double normalizeValue(double value, double min, double max, double newMin, double newMax) {

        return (value - min) * (newMax - newMin) / (max - min) + newMin;

    }

    public static double clamp(double value, double min, double max) {

        if (Double.compare(value, min) < 0)
            return min;

        if (Double.compare(value, max) > 0)
            return max;

        return value;
    }   


    /**
     * Perlin noise generator
     * 
     * // JAVA REFERENCE IMPLEMENTATION OF IMPROVED NOISE - COPYRIGHT 2002 KEN PERLIN.
     * // http://mrl.nyu.edu/~perlin/paper445.pdf
     * // http://mrl.nyu.edu/~perlin/noise/
     */
    public final static class ImprovedNoise {
    static public double noise(double x, double y, double z) {
       int X = (int)Math.floor(x) & 255,                  // FIND UNIT CUBE THAT
           Y = (int)Math.floor(y) & 255,                  // CONTAINS POINT.
           Z = (int)Math.floor(z) & 255;
       x -= Math.floor(x);                                // FIND RELATIVE X,Y,Z
       y -= Math.floor(y);                                // OF POINT IN CUBE.
       z -= Math.floor(z);
       double u = fade(x),                                // COMPUTE FADE CURVES
              v = fade(y),                                // FOR EACH OF X,Y,Z.
              w = fade(z);
       int A = p[X  ]+Y, AA = p[A]+Z, AB = p[A+1]+Z,      // HASH COORDINATES OF
           B = p[X+1]+Y, BA = p[B]+Z, BB = p[B+1]+Z;      // THE 8 CUBE CORNERS,

       return lerp(w, lerp(v, lerp(u, grad(p[AA  ], x  , y  , z   ),  // AND ADD
                                      grad(p[BA  ], x-1, y  , z   )), // BLENDED
                              lerp(u, grad(p[AB  ], x  , y-1, z   ),  // RESULTS
                                      grad(p[BB  ], x-1, y-1, z   ))),// FROM  8
                      lerp(v, lerp(u, grad(p[AA+1], x  , y  , z-1 ),  // CORNERS
                                      grad(p[BA+1], x-1, y  , z-1 )), // OF CUBE
                              lerp(u, grad(p[AB+1], x  , y-1, z-1 ),
                                      grad(p[BB+1], x-1, y-1, z-1 ))));
    }
    static double fade(double t) { return t * t * t * (t * (t * 6 - 15) + 10); }
    static double lerp(double t, double a, double b) { return a + t * (b - a); }
    static double grad(int hash, double x, double y, double z) {
       int h = hash & 15;                      // CONVERT LO 4 BITS OF HASH CODE
       double u = h<8 ? x : y,                 // INTO 12 GRADIENT DIRECTIONS.
              v = h<4 ? y : h==12||h==14 ? x : z;
       return ((h&1) == 0 ? u : -u) + ((h&2) == 0 ? v : -v);
    }
    static final int p[] = new int[512], permutation[] = { 151,160,137,91,90,15,
    131,13,201,95,96,53,194,233,7,225,140,36,103,30,69,142,8,99,37,240,21,10,23,
    190, 6,148,247,120,234,75,0,26,197,62,94,252,219,203,117,35,11,32,57,177,33,
    88,237,149,56,87,174,20,125,136,171,168, 68,175,74,165,71,134,139,48,27,166,
    77,146,158,231,83,111,229,122,60,211,133,230,220,105,92,41,55,46,245,40,244,
    102,143,54, 65,25,63,161, 1,216,80,73,209,76,132,187,208, 89,18,169,200,196,
    135,130,116,188,159,86,164,100,109,198,173,186, 3,64,52,217,226,250,124,123,
    5,202,38,147,118,126,255,82,85,212,207,206,59,227,47,16,58,17,182,189,28,42,
    223,183,170,213,119,248,152, 2,44,154,163, 70,221,153,101,155,167, 43,172,9,
    129,22,39,253, 19,98,108,110,79,113,224,232,178,185, 112,104,218,246,97,228,
    251,34,242,193,238,210,144,12,191,179,162,241, 81,51,145,235,249,14,239,107,
    49,192,214, 31,181,199,106,157,184, 84,204,176,115,121,50,45,127, 4,150,254,
    138,236,205,93,222,114,67,29,24,72,243,141,128,195,78,66,215,61,156,180
    };
    static { for (int i=0; i < 256 ; i++) p[256+i] = p[i] = permutation[i]; }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }


}
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Looks awesome.  Are you planning to add axis values?

Comment: Yes, I already have (commented code in example). But it for some reason distorts the walls, so sthat they aren't aligend. I'll have to create a separate group for it. And I still hope that José comes up with something better :-)

Answer (score 1):

Jzy3d supports various versions of JavaFX, you can [try this in this sample project](https://github.com/jzy3d/jzy3d-guide-fx). You will basically have to setup your project with Maven to [define dependencies to Jzy3D and JavaFX](https://github.com/jzy3d/jzy3d-guide-fx/blob/main/jzy3d-guide-javafx-jdk17/pom.xml#L18) (JavaFX must installed separately hence the "provided" scope).

I advise you to [refer to this sample code](https://github.com/jzy3d/jzy3d-guide-fx/blob/main/jzy3d-guide-javafx-jdk17/src/main/java/org/jzy3d/demos/javafx/DemoJavaFX_SwingNode.java) (or pick some other in the same example project)

```
    package org.jzy3d.demos.javafx;

import org.jzy3d.chart.Chart;
import org.jzy3d.chart.factories.ChartFactory;
import org.jzy3d.colors.Color;
import org.jzy3d.colors.ColorMapper;
import org.jzy3d.colors.colormaps.ColorMapRainbow;
import org.jzy3d.javafx.swing.JavaFXSwingChartFactory;
import org.jzy3d.maths.Range;
import org.jzy3d.plot3d.builder.Mapper;
import org.jzy3d.plot3d.builder.SurfaceBuilder;
import org.jzy3d.plot3d.primitives.Shape;
import org.jzy3d.plot3d.rendering.canvas.Quality;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 * Demonstrate how to use swing charts to display 3D image in a JavaFX SwingNode.
 * 
 * @author Martin Pernollet
 */
// --module-path /Users/martin/Dev/javafx-sdk-19/lib --add-modules javafx.base --add-opens javafx.base/com.sun.javafx=ALL-UNNAMED --add-modules javafx.controls --add-opens javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens javafx.graphics/javafx.stage=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.util=ALL-UNNAMED   --add-opens javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.stage=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.geom=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.geom.transform=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism=ALL-UNNAMED
public class DemoJavaFX_SwingNode extends Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Application.launch(args);
  }

  @Override
  public void start(Stage stage) {
    
    stage.setTitle(DemoJavaFX_SwingNode.class.getSimpleName());

    // Jzy3d
    JavaFXSwingChartFactory factory = new JavaFXSwingChartFactory();
    Chart chart = getChart(factory);

    factory.open(chart, stage);
  }

  private Chart getChart(ChartFactory factory) {
    // Define a function to plot
    Mapper mapper = new Mapper() {
      @Override
      public double f(double x, double y) {
        return x * Math.sin(x * y);
      }
    };

    // Create the object to represent the function over the given range.
    final Shape surface = new SurfaceBuilder().orthonormal(mapper, new Range(-3, 3), 80);
    surface.setColorMapper(new ColorMapper(new ColorMapRainbow(), surface, new Color(1, 1, 1, .5f)));
    surface.setFaceDisplayed(true);
    surface.setWireframeDisplayed(false);

    // Create a chart
    Quality quality = Quality.Advanced();
    Chart chart = factory.newChart(quality);
    chart.getScene().getGraph().add(surface);
    return chart;
  }
}
```

You can get a more general understanding of Jzy3D from the [online guide](https://doc.jzy3d.org/guide/docs/getting-started-charts) and even get lof a sample code [here](https://doc.jzy3d.org/guide/docs/subscriptions-guide.html) and  [here](https://github.com/jzy3d/jzy3d-api/tree/master/jzy3d-tutorials/src/main/java/org/jzy3d/demos).

[image: surface chart]

Comment: The repository which you try people to refer has been removed.

Comment: Indeed. The JavaFX extension is now integrated in the [main API](https://github.com/jzy3d/jzy3d-api/blob/master/jzy3d-native-jogl-javafx/pom.xml#L13).

Comment: Thank God you replied! I downloaded entire directory i.e. jzy3d-native-jogl-javafx, Now I wanted to run this application to obtain the same graph whi is given. I am encoutering errors like "Cannot resolve symbol 'javafx". Java FX library is not availble & I am trying to import it but not able to, Could you please let me know the way to resolve these dependency issues? This will be a help to the newbies & community.

Comment: I updated the the post - you should now have everything required.