# 3D surface JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, 3d, surface, javafx-3d

I am trying to implement my own 3D surface animation in JavaFX but i do not understand everything like it should works, could someone help me with understanding which should go where ?

- Already know that to build Mesh by using class need class object `TraingleMesh` and then have to add points by using method `mesh.getPoints.addAll(...);` but.. my `Function<Double, Double>` after using `apply` method does not help me at all, cuz the first argument has to be array float type, not `double` variable after applying some data.

  - How could i solve that problem ?
- I found some implementations of texture and faces created by @Roland here :

[3D surface - stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31073007/how-to-create-a-3d-surface-chart-with-javafx)

- How textures and faces working ?

It's really important for me, thanks for help!

Comment: Is this about animating a changing texture on a "constant" surface or about changing the surface?

Comment: It will change the surface with the new data based on the time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the FXyz [library](https://github.com/Birdasaur/FXyz). It is open source, and you can learn from the code.

For textures, have a look at this [post](http://jperedadnr.blogspot.com/2015/01/creating-and-texturing-javafx-3d-shapes.html).

FXyz has a `SurfacePlotMesh` class that does exactly what you want: plot a 3D surface based on a function `g = f(x,y)`, by using a `Function<Point2D, Number> function` parameter.

It also includes texturing, so you can include a density map in terms of `Function<Point3D, Number> density`. Each value is mapped to a color.

Check this test `Function2DPlotTest` [here](https://github.com/Birdasaur/FXyz/blob/master/src/org/fxyz/tests/Function2DPlotTest.java).

With this code snippet you can plot a function:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    PerspectiveCamera camera = new PerspectiveCamera(true);   
    camera.setTranslateZ(-30);
    SurfacePlotMesh surface = new SurfacePlotMesh(
            p-> Math.sin(p.magnitude() + 1e-10) / (p.magnitude() + 1e-10), 
            20, 20, 100, 100, 4); 
    surface.setCullFace(CullFace.NONE);
    surface.setTextureModeVertices3D(1530, p -> p.magnitude());
    surface.getTransforms().addAll(new Rotate(200, Rotate.X_AXIS), new Rotate(-20, Rotate.Y_AXIS));

    final Group group = new Group(surface);
    Scene scene = new Scene(group, 600, 400, true, SceneAntialiasing.BALANCED);
    scene.setCamera(camera);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show(); 
}
```

[image: SurfacePlotMesh]

And if you add a density map:

```
surface.setTextureModeVertices3D(1530, p -> p.magnitude());
```

you'll get this:

[image: Textured SurfacePlotMesh]

Now if you want an animation of the surface, you just need to create one:

```
private SurfacePlotMesh surface;
private long lastEffect;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    PerspectiveCamera camera = new PerspectiveCamera(true);   
    camera.setTranslateZ(-30);
    surface = new SurfacePlotMesh(
            p-> Math.sin(p.magnitude() + 1e-10) / (p.magnitude() + 1e-10), 
            20, 20, 100, 100, 4); 
    surface.setCullFace(CullFace.NONE);
    surface.setTextureModeVertices3D(1530, p -> p.magnitude());
    surface.getTransforms().addAll(new Rotate(200, Rotate.X_AXIS), new Rotate(-20, Rotate.Y_AXIS));

    final Group group = new Group(surface);
    Scene scene = new Scene(group, 600, 400, true, SceneAntialiasing.BALANCED);
    scene.setCamera(camera);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show(); 

    lastEffect = System.nanoTime();
    AtomicInteger count=new AtomicInteger();
    AnimationTimer timerEffect = new AnimationTimer() {

        @Override
        public void handle(long now) {
            if (now > lastEffect + 1_000_000_000l) {
                double t = (count.get() % 5 + 1);
                surface.setFunction2D(p -> Math.sin(t * p.magnitude() + 1e-10)/(t * p.magnitude() + 1e-10));
                count.getAndIncrement();
                lastEffect = now;
            }
        }
    };
    timerEffect.start();
}
```

And you'll get your surface animation:

[image: SurfacePlotMesh 2]

[image: SurfacePlotMesh 3]

[image: SurfacePlotMesh 4]

Comment: I included jar's to java project and it doesnt work, still have for exmaple on "SurfacePlotMesh" cannot resolve symbol.

Comment: What version of Java are you using? What are your imports?  Maybe you are missing the correct import?

Comment: I solved that problem by importing the all source to the project, not only jar's

Comment: You shouldn't have to do that, it is not the right way. What IDE are you using? What build system? (Ant, Maven, Gradle etc)