# how to use surface plotter or jzy3d with Intellij idea and gradle and javafx

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, javafx, jzy3d

I can't connect any of the above libraries.
Here is my project folder:
[image]

build.gradle file,
[image]

import error picture
[image]

and

IDEA's Project Structure dialog
[image]

Comment: Do you have "org.jzu3d" added to Gradle repository?

Comment: When you use Gradle you don't have to manually place the dependency JARs in your project directory. Simply specify the needed repositories and the appropriate dependency coordinates and Gradle will download the JARs from the repository into a customizable location on your computer. Gradle will then put those JARs on the classpath/modulepath as needed. If you absolutely need to manually add local JARs to your dependencies, then see [How to add local .jar file dependency to build.gradle file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20700053/6395627).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**JZY3D**

If you check the repository of the library at https://github.com/jzy3d/jzy3d-api, you will see different possible artifacts that you can use. Since you tagged your question with #javafx, I'd guess you need `jzy3d-javafx`.

If you search for it in the [Maven repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jzy3d/jzy3d-javafx), you will find the latest version available (1.0.2), and also an indication that this artifact is *not* available from MavenCentral, but from the [jzy3D releases](http://maven.jzy3d.org/releases) repository.

Therefore, in your build gradle you will need to include that repository and that dependency:

```
plugins {
  id 'application'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url "http://maven.jzy3d.org/releases"
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.jzy3d:jzy3d-javafx:1.0.2'
}

mainClassName = "your.Main"
```

This is the result of running the JavaFX demo from the [jyz3d repository](https://github.com/jzy3d/jzy3d-api/blob/master/jzy3d-javafx/src/main/java/org/jzy3d/demos/javafx/DemoJzy3dFX.java):

[image: jzy3d]

However, I couldn't run that on Java 11, because some illegal reflective operations that lead to a runtime exception:

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.jogamp.common.os.NativeLibrary$3 (file:/Users/<user>/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jogamp.gluegen/gluegen-rt/2.3.2/edc35ccfc13d4a4ad02c50d580874c18bf48bbef/gluegen-rt-2.3.2.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.findLibrary(java.lang.String)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.jogamp.common.os.NativeLibrary$3
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

so this only runs for me with Java 8 (which is not a good sign...).

**SurfacePlotter**

This is the repository link: https://github.com/ericaro/surfaceplotter, and you can find it on MavenCentral: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.ericaro/surfaceplotter/2.0.1

However, this is a very old release for Swing, so maybe you can manage to include it in a SwingNode..

**JavaFX alternatives**

If you want to plot surfaces with pure JavaFX 3D, running on Java 11+, you could also use [`SurfacePlotMesh`](https://github.com/FXyz/FXyz/blob/master/FXyz-Core/src/main/java/org/fxyz3d/shapes/primitives/SurfacePlotMesh.java) from the [FXyz library](https://github.com/FXyz/FXyz).

This question [3D surface JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37225197/3d-surface-javafx) has a sample on how to use it.

Your build should be something like:

```
plugins {
    id 'application'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.8'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url = "http://maven.jzy3d.org/releases"
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.fxyz3d:fxyz3d:0.5.2'
}

javafx {
    modules = [ 'javafx.controls' ]
}

mainClassName = 'your.Main'
```

[image: FXyz3D]